# Firebase not showing current version in Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

A few months ago I was forced to migrate my project from Fabric to Crashlytics. After releasing a newer version a week ago, bugs from the older verions started appearing in Firebase but not the ones from the current version.
When I navigate to "Latest release" tab I can see my new release labeled as "Needs investigation". 
Then when I click on "View crash details" the Crashlytics tab opens with a filter Versions = "1.7.4.15*" 
After a moment, before the page loads a message appears, saying "Invalid versions were removed from the filter".

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Hi Jan, I am also facing the same issue. Do you have any update on it?

Comment: @Karan_Rana I tried contacting Google but we could not make it work. I would suggest deleting the project in Firebase and recreating it. This is unfortunately not something that I could try, since I have already started using Firebase Messaging on production.

Comment: I have same problem, no news?

Comment: Facing the same issue, and not that fabric is gone, deleting project on firebase is not an option

Comment: Any news on that? @GauriGadkari I am also facing the same issue,

Comment: @SyedaZunaira have reached out to firebase support, waiting to hear from them.

Comment: @SyedaZunaira have reached out to firebase support, waiting to hear from them.

Comment: Anyone found answer on this, I'm also struggling with this error.

Comment: @GauriGadkari Any news from the support? I tried contacting them too, but they weren't able to fix my problem so I had to reach for solution below.

Comment: @JanMálek nothing concrete, we just created a new build for the same version and started seeing it

Comment: Any news on this? I have the same issue, my app is in production and it's not showing versions 1.1.11 and 1.1.12, which are not invalid at all...It's not a migrated project from Fabric, it's a new project we created directly with Firebase Crashlytics.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't make the migrated project working for latest version, so what I did was I created a new project, so that at least Crashlytics for newer versions would work.
The problem is, that all Firebase codes must be changed both on frontend and backend (e.g. Firebase Messaging)